# Change the command prompt based on username

Tags: bash, command-prompt

I use a single `~/.bashrc` file in all my machines that log in and I have the following line to display the command prompt

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

I don't want to see the username if it is 'sudar' but want to see it otherwise. How can I change the above line to drop the username part if it is equal to 'sudar'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [[ $USER == sudar ]]
then 
  PS1="THINGS YOU WANT IN PS1 VARIABLE"
else
  PS1="THINGS YOU WANT IN PS1 VARIABLE"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I have to wait another 3 minutes to accept it :) BTW what variable I have to use to check for host?